# Powershell Scripting Code Execution Issue After Adding a While Loop

Tags: powershell, networking, scripting

I am trying to write a Powershell script that communicates with some java server code. The script calls the following function to communicate with the server and currently the server is just printing out the message it receives.

```
Function Send-StringOverTcp ( 
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)][String]$DataToSend, 
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)][UInt16]$Port)
{
    Try {
        $IPAddress = "XX.XXX.XX.X"                          #ip of server
        $IPAddress = [IPAddress]$IPAddress.Trim()

        $ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"
        $TCPClient  = New-Object Net.Sockets.TcpClient
        $IPEndpoint = New-Object Net.IPEndPoint($IPAddress, $Port)
        $TCPClient.Connect($IPEndpoint)
        Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green "Connection established with 
$IPAddress on port $Port"

        $NetStream  = $TCPClient.GetStream()
        [Byte[]]$Buffer = [Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes($DataToSend)
        $NetStream.Write($Buffer, 0, $Buffer.Length)
        $NetStream.Flush()  
        Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green "Data sent to server"

        while($true) {

        }

        If ($NetStream) { $NetStream.close() }
        If ($TCPClient) { $TCPClient.close() }
    } catch {
    Write-Error $_.Exception.ToString()
    Read-Host -Prompt "The above error occurred. Press Enter to exit."
    }
}
```

In the script when I don't have the while loop before I close the TCPClient, the message is sent to the server and the server prints it out with no issues. However when I add this while loop the script never actually sends the message to the server code until after the while loop finishes. Is there any way to get the lines

```
$NetStream.Write($Buffer, 0, $Buffer.Length)
$NetStream.Flush()
```

to execute before the while loop ends. Is there a reason Powershell isn't executing those statements in the correct order before the while loop instead of after it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm still not sure what caused Powershell to act this way. In case anyone is having a similar issue I worked around this by just pulling the while loop out into it's own function and calling that with no issues.